# REST/JSON -- field in response is silently incremented by browser?

Tags: javascript, rest, typescript

I'm building a JavaScript application (React/etc.) that consumes REST resources from a companion server (written in Spring Boot/REST/JPA).

Mostly, I'm pulling either lists of entities or single entities --

- `.../rest/tasks?page=0`
- `.../rest/tasks/1234567`

-- where each entity looks like:

```
{
  "id" : 20180501150819347,
  "requested" : "2018-05-01T19:08:19.353+0000",
  "cancelled" : null,
  "delayUntil" : null,
  "started" : "2018-05-01T19:08:30.140+0000",
  "ended" : "2018-05-01T19:08:31.610+0000",
  "status" : "complete",
  ...
```

**The Problem** is that, for whatever reason, the "id" field on my entity is being incremented!

For example:

**1.** I make the request: `/rest/tasks`, to get a list of submitted Tasks.

**2.** The resulting response looks like:

```
...
"tasks": [ {
  "id" : 20180501150819347,
  ...
```

This is correct: a Task entity by that ID does exist in my database.

**3.** The JSON response is then given to my application as:

```
...
"tasks": [ {
  "id" : 20180501150819348,
  ...
```

**4.** I can definitely retrieve that entity via `rest/tasks/...9347` -- but, as in (2) and (3), the resulting JSON object has the incorrect (incremented) ID.

The weird part is: this appears to be happening at the *browser*-level. When, for instance, I inspect the network request/response in Chrome, I see that the **raw** response contains the correct ID, and the pretty-printed response contains the incorrect (incremented) ID. I've verified this with both Chrome (66.0.3359.139) and Firefox (59.0.3).

However, this is the only entity-type which manifests such behavior. I've tested all my other entity-types (with both `int` and `long` IDs). This behavior is consistent across multiple restarts (both application and browser).

[Chrome - response (raw)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7bFU.png)

[Chrome - response (pretty-printed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdCbe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a problem with rounding. The number 20180501150819347 is greater than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. JavaScript (and TypeScript) represent all numbers as floating point numbers, so, numbers greater than that constant can't be correctly represented. Unfortunately, JavaScript does not have a pure integer type, or a long integer.

You can check this behaviour  here:

```js
var num = 20180501150819347;

console.log(num);
```

As you see, `console.log` prints the next number, the same that happens to you.

As you're dealing with IDs, my advice is that you change the type of the `id` property to `string`. It won't matter on the server-side, but will prevent rounding from ocurring in client side:

```
...
"tasks": [ {
  "id" : "20180501150819347",
  ...
}, ...]
```

Comment: Ahhh, that makes sense. I had thought it was something to do with max-lengths -- but my other entities with "long" IDs were doing just fine (albeit with much numerically-smaller values).